# Puppet executes classes in the wrong order

Tags: windows, puppet, puppet-enterprise

The four modules mentioned below are what are there in my site.pp file.
These four modules are written by me, they inturn use the Forge modules.For example, `iis::install` uses `puppetlabs/windowsfeature` module to install IIS and `site::install` uses `puppetlabs/iis` to create website and appPool that I require.

The problem that I am encountering is - Puppet rightly starts execution with `iis::install` but it does not finish executing this class fully. It keeps it in the background and then starts executing `tools::install`. As a result of wrong execution order, it fails completely

I am facing the exact same issue with the other two classes as well. It just starts executing `site::install` and then proceeds to `include site::install`. At the end, after the remaining classes complete execution, the classes in the background proceeds their execution

How can I inform Puppet in Site.pp file to complete the execution of first class before proceeding to the next

```
 node default {
   include iis::install
   include tools::install   
   include site::install
   include deploy::execute
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please read this article about resources [ordering in puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html).

E.g you can use [chaining arrows](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html#syntax-chaining-arrows) to define order between classes:

```
Class['iis::install'] -> Class['tools::install'] -> 
Class['site::install'] -> Class['deploy::execute']
```